# Confusing sacct Job Accounting Fields: `TresUsage[In|Out][Max|Tot]`

Tags: slurm

We currently run

```bash
$ sacct --version
slurm 21.08.6
```

and I am utterly confused about the various Job Accounting fiels.

Looking at `man sacct` under `Job Accounting Fields` we see numerous TRES fields, but I don't get the difference between `Max`/`Tot` and `In`/`Out`.
Here are the specific sections from the man page for convenience.

```
TresUsageInMax
    Tres maximum usage in by all tasks in job.  NOTE: If corresponding TresUsageInMaxTask is -1 the metric is node centric instead of task.
TresUsageInTot
    Tres total usage in by all tasks in job.
TresUsageOutMax
    Tres maximum usage out by all tasks in job.  NOTE: If corresponding TresUsageOutMaxTask is -1 the metric is node centric instead of task.
TresUsageOutTot
    Tres total usage out by all tasks in job.
```

The same can be seen here https://slurm.schedmd.com/archive/slurm-21.08.6/sacct.html#OPT_TresUsageInAve (start of TRES fields).

So, what is the difference between `TresUsage[In|Out][Max|Tot]`?

## Edit: example output

```
          JobID                                                               TRESUsageInMax                                                              TRESUsageInTot         TRESUsageOutMax          TRESUsageOutTot
---------------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------
          63585 
    63585.batch         cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=226001,mem=12036K,pages=0,vmem=384828K        cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=226001,mem=12036K,pages=0,vmem=384828K  energy=0,fs/disk=23316   energy=0,fs/disk=23316
        63585.0           cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=67990,mem=4136K,pages=1,vmem=310188K    cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=3837106,mem=262636K,pages=2,vmem=19852032K   energy=0,fs/disk=3462  energy=0,fs/disk=217538
        63585.1           cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=67990,mem=4136K,pages=0,vmem=310188K    cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=4009672,mem=262344K,pages=0,vmem=19852032K   energy=0,fs/disk=3462  energy=0,fs/disk=218831
        63585.2           cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=67990,mem=4148K,pages=0,vmem=310188K    cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=3857338,mem=262232K,pages=0,vmem=19852032K   energy=0,fs/disk=3462  energy=0,fs/disk=217739
```

Comment: Well, common sense tells me that Max is the maximum of the usages while Tot is the sum of the usages. Regarding In and Out... is it talking about things that comes in and things that goes out? Does it make sense?

Comment: @poshi, I added some example job output. Well, the tot / max relation are blindingly obvious, though it doesn't lift my confusion. The max over a job step makes sense, but what is the total mem / fs/disk? Is it the sum over mem / fs/disk of every second of the job step? Well, the in/out association you mentioned is what the name implies, but it doesn't really explain.

Comment: Common sense again: "what is the total mem / fs/disk?". I think it is the total memory / file system/disk transfers used in the job step during the whole job. It doesn't make sense to sum the current value every second, they are just the resources used by the task. Regarding in and out, when applied to FS or network, it can be data read (in) and data written (out).

Comment: I still have to understand why the FS out Max and Tot do not match, as to me, the maximum output written to disk in the tasks is equivalent to the total.

Comment: @poshi How is "total memory / file system/disk transfers used in the job step during the whole job" different from the sum over the values every second because that should exactly give what you describe?!
Regarding why Max and Tot are not equivalent, (at least to my understanding) consider two different transfers at different times, Max only gets the larger value while tot is the sum of both.

Comment: Let's say you have a process that runs for 10s and consumes 1B of memory during all this time. To me, 1B is the total memory used. But if you make the sum of the consumed memory every second, you are adding up 1B 10 times (because you do it for each second in 10s), so you get 10B as a result. this number tells nothing to me and is clearly different from 1B.

Comment: Regarding the transfer example, let's say that a process transfers 1B at the beginning and another 1B at the end of its execution. At the end of the process, the total transferred bytes is 2B. And the maximum number of bytes transferred is also 2B (distributed in two transfers in this case, but it could be any distribution).

Comment: Maximum per periods shorter than the whole duration of the task could make sense, but the definition is the maximum of the task, so you have to take into account all the transfers made during the task, which, BTW, are indistinguishable to SLURM (maybe you know there are N different transfers, but SLURM just sees bytes in, bytes out).

Answer (score 2):

The `TresUsage[In|Ou]Max` is the maximum over all tasks of the maximum over time of that Tres usage.

The `TresUsage[In|Ou]Tot` is the sum over all tasks of the maximum over time of that Tres usage.

The `In|Out` differentiator is only relevant for `Tres` that can be ingress or egress such as disk read (`In`) and writes (`Out`), or network incoming transfers (`In`) and outgoing transfers (`Out`).